# border-image rounding not rounding correctly in Safari

Tags: css, safari

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9TWHF/1/

```
#bigdescription{
    width: 66%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 87px 78px 81px 79px; 
    -moz-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 78 81 79 round; 
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 78 81 79 round;
    -o-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 78 81 79 round; 
    border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 78 81 79 fill round; 
}
```

Firefox:
[image]

Safari:
[image]

You can see it best on the bottom border. In every browser but Safari, the bottom border rounds correctly. In Safari, it doesn't seem to be rounding at all. Any ideas why it's happening?

Edit: as far as I can tell, Safari doesn't actually support the "round" repeat style on border-image (even though their docs says that they do https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html)

Comment: Probably a sub-pixel/ rounding difference in rendering since you are using a % for width but your image dimensions are px values.

Comment: I tried explicitly setting the width with a pixel value but it still doesn't round :(

Comment: Safari on Mac or on Windows?

Comment: Safari on Mac and iOS. Must be a webkit issue.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue on Safari-Mac but instead of a rough cut the image is over-stretched

Comment: Is this bug in Safari still not fixed in 2021?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a Safari bug. [It does the same thing here](http://border-image.com/#%7B%22src%22%3a%22http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png%22,%22linkBorder%22%3atrue,%22borderWidth%22%3a%5B0,0,0,0%5D,%22imageOffset%22%3a%5B47,78,70,78%5D,%22fill%22%3atrue,%22setRepat%22%3afalse,%22repeat%22%3a%5B%22round%22,%22round%22%5D,%22scaleFactor%22:3,%22setRepeat%22%3atrue%7D), even with their sample image.
It appears the only way to get consistent results is with fixed width for Safari...

Comment: What do you mean by fixed width?

Comment: Basically setting the width to a static value using something like "px" values. If you look at the question, they have `width: 66%;`, so that width is dynamic meaning it can change with the page/parent width. The other answers on this thread us a width having `px` values. So I would consider `width: 350px;` to be a static or fixed width.

Comment: Weird that doesn't fix the issue in Safari for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I can get it to look right and smooth.

```
#bigdescription{
width: 353px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 87px 64px 76px 89px; 
-webkit-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 64 76 89 round; 
   -moz-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 64 76 89 round; 
     -o-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 64 76 89 round; 
        border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 64 76 89 round;
}
```

I changed some of the width: and the border round properties

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of @Piyush-Marvaniya

It seems to be due to pixel rounding errors in connection with width in percentage. At fixed with you get the border similar to the other browsers.

Here's the working example in Saf v5.0 (7533.16)/Win at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/9TWHF/7/).
I've been able to make it nearly perfect, there's one pixel glitch in the border's lower curve, but you have to look very closely to realize it:

```
#bigdescription {
    width: 350px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 87px 69px 76px 89px; 
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 69 76 89 round; 
       -moz-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 69 76 89 round; 
         -o-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 69 76 89 round; 
            border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 69 76 89 round;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this css

```
#bigdescription{
        width: 66%;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 87px 69px 77px 89px; 
        -moz-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 69 77 89 round; 
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 69 77 89 round; 
        -o-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 69 77 89 round; 
        border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/nJ71Mj5.png) 87 69 77 89 fill round; 
    }
```

Comment: No dice, still not rounding and the curves don't match up nicely.