# Border-image in Safari cutting image?

Tags: css, safari

I have a border-image and its working fine, but not in safari.

In Google Chrome:

[image: Chrome:]

In Safari:

[image: Screenshot from iPad]

As you can see, the border-image is cut in safari. Any suggestions? The Css code:

```
border:40px solid transparent;
border-image:url(../images/charts/leistungsangebot/ruler.png) 150 0 round;
-webkit-border-image:url(../images/charts/leistungsangebot/ruler.png) 150 0 round;
border-left:0;
border-right:0;
border-bottom:0;
width:500px;
height:100px;
margin-top:100px;
background-color:white;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post below has some good info about the border-image problem in Safari:

[border-image rounding not rounding correctly in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390896/border-image-rounding-not-rounding-correctly-in-safari)

In short, I don't think Safari really supports the 'round' property and instead defaults to 'repeat'.

One possible solution is to use an image that is the exact size you want your top border to be.
For example, if you want the top border to be exactly 500px wide and 40px high, then make the image "ruler.png" exactly that size.

Comment: Sad, I can't use a fixed width, but I guess I will have to! Thank you for your answer.